# How did Mello know how to help Near in Death Note?

Tags: death-note

In the end of Death Note, Near would've been lost if Mello didn't help him. That makes me think why Near who is always be careful (isn't like L or Mello) didn't find out about the possibility of fake death note, meanwhile Mello had found out about that.

For Mello, after he found out that Kira helped Japan Police, he would found out that Kira was there being watched by others. In order to keep killing people, he would need X-Kira (Mikami) to do the killings and a spokeperson (Takada) to help him communicate with him. Until then, Mello's and Near's thinking were the same: find the x-kira (Mello investigated Misa too). Mello could easily assume that Near had found the x-kira and been stalking him.

What makes it weird is Mello thought that this person who was being investigated by Near was using fake death note, and assumed that Near wouldn't ever found out about this unless he kidnapped Takada.

So, would Near have never found out about the possibility of fake Death Note without Mello sacrificing himself? If it was really that hard to find out, how could Mello know? Doesn't it sound like Near would get easily be tricked by Light, while Mello outsmarted the two of them?

Comment: N and Kila played a game of chess and are progressing to the end game. At this point, both of them belive that they have ever single move concidered and planned. Now M hears N's entire plan (I belive while droping by getting the picture) and "sees the board" as N has planed his checkmate. Everything that N planned is now given for M, M can analyse that single position and finds the trick that (M and) Kira would play. M didn't know that Kira had that plan but M knew that this was a weak spot at N's plan. N was sure that he outsmarted Kira and M considered how Kira might have outsmarted N.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I remember that Halle Lidner, SPK member, always kept in touch with Mello, keeping him up-to-date with Near's latest theories concerning Kira case. It's possible that he also knew about Near's plan and his appointment with Kira.

However, Mello, with Matt, decided to kidnap Takada that made the real Death Note location revealed.

Before that, Mello's movements are unknown since the story focus on Takada and Mikami investigation. His reason to kidnap Takada is also unknown whether because he realized the possibility of fake Death Note or other reason.

But in the end, Near acknowledged Mello that he wouldn't have won without his sacrifice.

Comment: We can probably assume that this was not how Mello intended this kidnapping to go, if we look at his reaction to the death of Matt. 

He would not have known about the slip of Death Note hidden in Takada's bra, and, presumably, thought both himself and Matt relatively safe. 

With information being fed to him via Halle, he would probably have reached similar conclusions to Near and realised something drastic needed to be done to reveal the location of the real Death Note. Knowing Nears team were watching, he would hope to would flush it out and get the information back via Halle.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, whilst Near was still operating (mainly) inside the law, Mello had much more freedom (and, personallity wise, is generally more likely to) to attempt these drastic moves that Near could not. Whether Near would be counting on or hoping for something like this, we can only speculate upon.

Comment: sequoiad So it's possible that Near also thought about the possibility of fake death note but didn't take any action for that yet and then Mello stepped forward helping him?

Comment: @sequoiad Oh and my personal thought is Near didn't realized that since Mikami was so convincing, while Mello after knowing what Near's plan was, maybe thought about the possibility of fake death note and kidnap Takada as what the least he could do for Near

Comment: it's possible, certainly. Mello could also have been attempting to push forwards his own investigation in a way that Near would not (I can't imagine Near ever using a similar method) as well, but it's all speculation as to whether he did it to help Near on purpose or not. I'm also wondering whether Near already might have had a plan ready (when he set the date for the warehouse meeting) to confirm and locate the fake and real Note, which he never needed to enact due to Mello's sudden and unpredictable action.

Answer (score 0):

The main point here are the differences between N, M and L. L was able to stay mostly calme while solving a case and had the ability to assume information wrong to not come into his own way. N is absolutely apathic, calm and logicly thinking. He can solve every "fair riddle" but lacks the ability to question the scope or to empathize with others (e.g. his "opponent"). M is the exact oposite, he is quick tempered but he is able to think like his opponent and he both cheats and plays assuming the other one cheats. He knew - like N - that Kira was aware of the investigations but unlike N he theorized that Kira would set a trap like he did. After he herad of N's plan and that "Kira to be prooven" accepted, he assumed a trick-in-trick and started the kidnap to ensure that the right DN is used by X-Kira and that N would take notice of it.

That's the anser: N solves a case like a puzzle, assuming that he just have to find every pice an it's place. M would allways assume that there are pices missing or extra or faked.

Answer (score -1):

That's because Lidner told Mello's plan and what made it weird was how Mello could find out there was a fake death note prepared by Mikami and thought to trap nearby? in my opinion because x guess (mikami) succeeded in knowing by near and near was increasingly focused on investigating mikami and light knowing near was investigating mikami light knowing near a genius then light planned a fake death note trap prepared by mikami to trap near from a month ago, now Mello could find out there was a fake death note because Mello thought the light smart person would definitely use the trap given to near just as Mello faced with Japanese police forces Light set a trap against Mello from there Mello had a thought that Light would put it trap to near so that mello thought there was a fake death note, now that I observed from all the comments of death note fans why did Mello sacrifice herself for near? all fans don't know it yet so I spill my knowledge here

because mello always said he wanted to be number one in the world because he sacrificed himself so that death note fans think that if mello doesn't sacrifice himself then near will die meaning that mello is superior to near mello smarter than near even though near is the successor of L That's impossible because Mello has sacrificed herself only, Mello did it only to guide .

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.